# Is it possible to get the window object from the event in handleEvent?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

As in the question... how to get the `window` object from an event fired in the `window` scope for example:

```
handleEvent: function(event) {

  // is window object available here and can we get it from event
}
```

I can get the `window` object from other APIs. I was wondering if it was possible to get it from the fired `event`.

Reference:
[handleEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)
[Code Snippet using handleEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: You really ought to provide some more context in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the answer ... any of these will get the `window` object from the event

`event.view` [event.view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.view)
`event.target.ownerDocument.defaultView` [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target)
`event.originalTarget.ownerGlobal` [event.originalTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.originalTarget) (Non-standard)

Comment: That's what it is! event.view awesome! thanks man! Really like that non-standard tip as well.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work, but it will work almost all the time.  It assumes that the event was fired on a GUI/DOM target (i.e. from within a browser). There are possibilities for which this may not be the `window` object.

Comment: @Makyen ... maybe... but I mean form a window environment... I will clarify my question

Comment: I had a "scroll" event listener and the handler function receives an `event` object.
`event.target.defaultView` returned the `window` object.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the event. But most usually yes you can. Do a console.log on the event then you might something like targetChromeWindow or something, this one I can't remember i came across it once though while doing something.

Most usually though, get event.target or relatedTarget or originalTarget (theres one more target i forgot what it is) and do ownerDocument.defaultView

If you want the chrome window from that you can get that by doing this:

```
var DOMWin = win.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
.rootTreeItem
.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
```

Comment: Thank you... that code is too long .. I can get the window with `Services.ww.activeWindow` easily .. I wanted to know if it was possible from the fired event ;)

Comment: Check out the event.target and others i listed abouve then doing a .ownerDocument.defaultView on it

Answer (score 1):

The following will populate the window and document variables if they do not already exist.  It should work from any scope/context:

```
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    //If there is no window defined, get the most recent.
    var window = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                           .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                           .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
}

if (typeof document === "undefined") {
    //If there is no document defined, get it
    var document = window.content.document;
}
```

Here are some additional variables which might be useful to have available, depending on what you are doing:

```
if (typeof gBrowser === "undefined") {
    //If there is no gBrowser defined, get it
    var gBrowser = window.gBrowser;
}

var tab = gBrowser.selectedTab;
var browserForTab = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab( tab );
var notificationBox = gBrowser.getNotificationBox( browserForTab );
var ownerDocument = gBrowser.ownerDocument;
```